# Continuously reading serial-port buffer and parsing data to array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, parsing, serial-port, buffer

Hello I'm trying to find best solution for continuously reading serial-port buffer and parsing data to array, continuously string form serial-port looks like this :

> "...G       130 g\r\nG       130 g\r\nG       124 g\r\nG       124 g\r\nG       124
>   g\r\nG...     "

The main idea is read for exaple last 3 data from serial-port broadcasting string, parse to double array [124.0; 124.0; 124.0] and comapre if equals.

Now I'm using this simple code but it is not enough fast :

```
_serialPortMainForm.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Port_DataReceived);
```

.....

```
void Port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
            {
                byte[] data = new byte[_serialPortMainForm.BytesToRead];
                _serialPortMainForm.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                string str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
                RawSerialPortData += str;
                if (RawSerialPortData.Length > Properties.Settings.Default.BufferSize) {
                    ProcessSerialPortData(RawSerialPortData);
                    RawSerialPortData = "";
                }
            }
```

And parsing data like this :

```
public void ProcessSerialPortData( string DataToProcess) {
            int count = 0;
            string PostFix = "";

            DataToProcess = DataToProcess.Substring(DataToProcess.IndexOf('G') + 1);
            DataToProcess = DataToProcess.Replace(" ", "");
            DataToProcess = DataToProcess.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "|");

            foreach (char c in DataToProcess) if (c == '|') count++;
            ProcessedData = new double[count-1];

            DataToProcess = DataToProcess.Replace("G", "");

            if (DataToProcess.Contains("kg")) { PostFix = "kg"; DataToProcess = DataToProcess.Replace("kg", ""); }
            if (DataToProcess.Contains("g")) { PostFix = "g"; DataToProcess = DataToProcess.Replace("g", ""); }

            UnitsController(PostFix);

            DataToProcess = DataToProcess.Replace(".", ",");
            string[] SplitData = DataToProcess.Split('|');

            int j = 0;
            while (j < count - 1) {

                Double.TryParse(SplitData[j], out ProcessedData[j]);
                j++;
            }
        }
```

Kg are irelevant for this situation because grams are enough for this situation

Have somenone any idea or simple and best solution how do this better and faster ??

Comment: I assume the buffer size is enough to hold three readings?

Comment: Also, is it always the same `PostFix` for all measurements? Or can it vary between measurements?

Comment: buffer holds aproximetly 10 readings... The data from serial port are stream, only numbers are changes postfix is same for all measurments..

Comment: code works widouth any issue but I thing that is not the best way how to parse data from stream. Because as you can see I copy part of stream every "Properties.Settings.Default.BufferSize" now it is set to 100 ...

Comment: I just posted an answer. Take a look. :-)

Comment: Can the values have decimals? (dots or commas)

Comment: I think no. Decimal is only for kilos. I saw your answare it looks good and much simplier tha my code :) , I'll try to test it na we will see... Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making certain assumptions about the string in the buffer, one could extract all values using Regex.

Declare a global variable outside the method and compile the Regex for faster results:

```
Regex _regex = new Regex(@"\d+\s+\w+", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Then in your method, use the following to extract all the values:

```
var matches = _regex.Matches(DataToProcess)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => 
    {
        var parts = m.Value.Split(' ');
        return new { Value = parts[0], Unit = parts[1] };
    });

//This is just for you to see the results in the console.
foreach (var value in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Assuming `DataToProcess` contains this:

```
var DataToProcess = @"G130 g\r\nG 130 g\r\nG 124 g\r\nG 124 g\r\nG 124 g\r\n";
```

This would yield the following in the console:

> > { Value = 130, Unit = g }
> >
> > { Value = 130, Unit = g }
> >
> > { Value = 124, Unit = g }
> >
> > { Value = 124, Unit = g }
> >
> > { Value = 124, Unit = g }

You can then use this enumeration to test for units, values, etc.

If you need the values as an array of doubles, just use:

```
var ProcessedData = matches.Select(m => Convert.ToDouble(m.Value)).ToArray();
```

Lastly, [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) is usually preferred in C# for variable names and your code doesn't seem very thread-safe. Something to think about.

Comment: Only values are enough, but is some possibility to convert string values to array of double values... something like ... TryParse ??

Comment: @Oliwer11: Sure. Just add a conversion to the last line. I will modify my answer.

Comment: @Oliwer11: My pleasure. :-)